# Define image in CSS, not in HTML

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm having an issue, and I'm not actually sure what is going wrong.

I have an HTML page, and my images are currently linked in as such.

```
<span class="tribar" onclick="openNav()"><img src="url_here"></span>
```

I was trying to eliminate all image urls from the HTML source code, and have them in the css. This is what I have tried.

```
<span class="tribar" onclick="openNav()"></span> // HTML

.tribar {
display: inline-block;
background-image: url("image_url") no-repeat top left;
width: 220px;
height: 220px;
}
```

But my HTML span is coming up blank, and I can't seem to figure it out.

This should be a simple mistake.

Comment: `no=repeat` is invalid in css

Comment: My bad, twas a typo on SO, my code does not reflect that. Still having the same issue.

Comment: Use `no-repeat` instead of `no=repeat`

Comment: Don't do this. You want something that people can click on to do something. That's a `<button>`, not a `<span>`. Buttons are interactive controls (they show up as such in screen readers, you can tab to them if you can't use a mouse, etc). You also want something to tell people what clicking on the button will do. That is Content, not Presentation. The right place to put content is HTML not CSS. Use an `<img>` and give it an `alt` attribute.

Comment: See my comment above, my code does have `no=repeat`. `no=repeat` was a typo on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend doing it with a `<button>`:

```js
function opennav() {
  alert("Hello!");
}
```

```css
.nav-button {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  font-size: 0; /*hide alt text*/
}

.nav-button:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: url(http://placekitten.com/220/220);
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button class="nav-button" onclick="opennav()">Alt text for screen readers</button>
```

See also on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/kis-nagy/pen/xQqPjQ).

Answer (score 3):

You can't use **"no-repeat"** value inside of the **"background-image:"** property.
You should add these two lines in your CSS Style instead:

```
background-position: top left;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

If you want to do it in one line, you should use **"background:"** property:

```
background: url("image_url") no-repeat top left;
```

ref.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to hold the image source in css as long as the url for the link or the code for the button is held on the page.

I recommend this way:

```css
a {
  display: block;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
}

.tribar {
  display: block;
  background-image: url("https://jobadder.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow.com-300.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span class="tribar" /></a>
```